# Getting CPU usage per Process of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I developed a Chrome-Extension and want to know if it is possible to get CPU usage of any tab in Chrome (please see the image)? I saw a few questions which are very old. Maybe there is some new techniques to get the CPU usage for each tab.

[image]

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#method-getProcessInfo is still in the dev channel and not yet available, but will provide more information about each running process.

Comment: i installed chrome dev and run the code chrome.processes.getProcessInfo but got following error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProcessInfo' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:18

Comment: Please update your question , insert getProcessInfo segment.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You need to request the permission: "processes" first in your `manifest.json` with something like:

```
{
  "name": "My extension...",
  ...
  "permissions": [ "processes" ],
  ...
}
```

If you are on dev-channel you'll have chrome.processes available. On other channels the extensions will be rejected with an error saying:

> 'processes' requires dev channel or newer, but this is the stable channel.

[image: chrome.processes in dev tools]