# Is it possible to write a Chrome extension that adds CPU usage to the tab name? e.g. [xx%] SiteName

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension

Chrome 81.

Would it be possible to build a Chrome extension with access to per-tab CPU usage, i.e. these numbers here: 
[image: cpuusage]

...and prepend them to the tab titles, e.g. for Gmail, instead of "**Inbox**" it would display as "**[51%] Inbox**". Or better yet, only do so if the 10-second average CPU usage crossed a user-defined threshold, e.g. 25%. The goal there being to identify tabs which might be draining your battery.

I took at look at [chrome.processes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes) but it seems it's still only available in the Dev channel, and even then, not sure what I am asking for is available using the API. I am also aware of a similar question such as [How to get cpu usage of current tab from chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844762/how-to-get-cpu-usage-of-current-tab-from-chrome) and [Getting CPU usage per Process of Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640168/getting-cpu-usage-per-process-of-chrome), but both of those remain unanswered at the time of this writing.

I am also aware of extensions such as [System Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/system-monitor/ecmlflnkenbdjfocclindonmigndecla) ([github](https://github.com/pd4d10/system-monitor)) but that appears to display the global system CPU usage, not per-tab stats.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is an official API for that. I guess it would be possible with a native extension and some clever digging around to get this information and pass it into an extension script eventually. I don't have a concrete example though. (Not sure that'd get approved in the Chrome store though.)

Comment: Judging by the documentation it seems quite trivial: either use chrome.processes.onUpdated listener or query the info per tab (chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab + chrome.processes.getProcessInfo). Then use a content script to update `document.title` in each tab.